# Using the central equation for inelastic collisions entropy change

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, collision

I have what appears to be a simple question but I seem to be missing something.

Take a constant temperature system where a ball travelling at $5ms^{-1}$ strikes a stationary ball and sticks to it in an inelastic collision.  They continue moving at a reduced velocity with no change in the system temperature.  Ignore energy transfer to surroundings what is the entropy change.

Okay so I want to use the central equation for this question but all I know is there is constant temperature and pressure.  So should I say $U = U(T,P)$ then expand $dU$ and $dV$ in terms of T and P. Then as T and P are constant and don't change they will just cancel in the integral.

So how do I apply the central equation to this problem as it seems my method is flawed.

Answer (score -1):

For inelastic collision, the ball deformation usually accompanies heat generation. To keep the system temperature constant, there should be some heat loss. This will increases the system's entropy.